# Java Skip Iteration 0

Tags: java, console-application

Im new at Java Console.

```
for (i=0;i<=noOfSP;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("NAME OF THE Plan #" + i + "?:  'Example input: 4GB' ");
        nameOfPlan = scn.nextLine();
        SubscriptionPlan subscriptionPlan = new SubscriptionPlan(nameOfPlan);
        if ( !gsmProvider.addSubscriptionPlan(subscriptionPlan) )
        {
            System.out.println("Adding Error. Program Will Closing.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

In this codeblock I wanna read name. I read "noOfSP" from user type of Integer. But iteration 0 won't work? If noOfSP is 0, program skips for loop ? Why?

EDIT: 
I edited inside the for loop. Okay but still can not read 0. iteration.

> NUMBER OF SUBSCRIPTION PLANS ? : 'Example input: 1' 
>   1
>   NAME OF THE Plan #0?:  'Example input: 4GB' 
>   NAME OF THE Plan #1?:  'Example input: 4GB'

The 0. iteration is skipped ? Why?

Comment: becouse `0` is not less than `0`

Comment: give <=0 it will work

Comment: because in the first loop i=0 when compare i<0, actually 0<0 is false, hence this loop directly exited!

Comment: Okay. I forget the 0. But when I was set noOfSP = 1, 0. iteration is skipped and 1. iteration work. In every loop I wanna read something but wont work in 0. iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution. Change

```
nameOfPlan = scn.nextLine();
```

To

```
nameOfPlan = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
```

Why?

When you input any value and hit enter, a new-line character will be appended to the end of your input. in your case, when you press enter for the `noOfSP` value, a new-line character (`/n`) was appended by default.

Since you have use `scn.nextInt()` for  `noOfSP` value (most probably), its only fetch the `int`, and there is still new-line characters (`\n`) left.
your first `for` loop iteration (iteration 0) fetch the `\n` thus, skip the `scn.nextLine()` in first iteration .

**Note:** you can also fix this by adding `scn.nextLine();` just before your `for` loop:

```
....
scn.nextLine();
for (i=0;i<=noOfSP;i++){
    .....
```

Comment: Thanks man ! But I wanna know why I have to create Scanner every iteration?

Answer (score 0):

As for loop says i value should be less than noOfSP, that's why it skips the loop.
Change for loop to

```
for (i=0;i<=noOfSP;i++)
```

Comment: Okay. I edit that but still continuous for 1 or more.

Comment: @MetehanToksoy: Means? For value 1 and more it will obviously loop

Comment: @MetehanToksoy: Would you separate each line from edited section.
"NUMBER OF SUBSCRIPTION PLANS ? : 'Example input: 1' 1 NAME OF THE Plan #0?: 'Example input: 4GB' NAME OF THE Plan #1?: 'Example input: 4GB'" I do not get anything from it :(

Comment: This is my Object Oriented lesson homework. User enter the Subscription number. If user Subscribed 2 subscription  enter 2 for example. And I must read subscription name in loop whichs are subscriped by user. This Subscription like GSM tariffs. For example " 1GB Internet + 500 Min" .

Answer (score 0):

if i=0 and noOfSP is 0 at start, (0<0) will return false
use this instead:

```
for(i=0; i<=noOfSP;i++)
```

Comment: By this way if I enter "1" program must loop 1 times but if I use "i<=noOfSP", program will loop 2 times. 

Thanks .